# Emacs: align text, but not the entire line?

Tags: emacs, indentation

The only editor I've ever used that supports this (I'm sure lots do, however) is Sublime Text 2, but hopefully emacs has a trick up its sleeve too.  Some classes I work on that have a fairly declarative syntax look cleaner if the source is kept columnized.  The problem comes in when a new row increases the length of a column by a space or two... you then have to work through each row re-aligning it.

A screenshot probably clarifies what I'm getting at:

[image: Columnized text out of alignment]

Here I've added a row in which one if its columns extends further than the other columns, so I'd like to realign it all again.  Ordinarily I'd just repeat-cycle my fingers around the arrows and the space bar until I've re-aligned everything row-by-row, but it'd be good if there was a way to just select a rectangular area and force text non-whitespace parts of that area to fall into alignment.

Is this possible?

Comment: Hah!  ___ editor does x, can Emacs do x?  Unless X is a horizontal scroll bar, then the answer is probably yes.  ;)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Rather than using rectangles, you could use `align-regexp`.  Select the area then do:

`C-u M-x align-regexp RET ,\(\s-*\) RET 1 RET 1 RET y`

If you do this a lot, make a function:

```
(defun my-align-after-commas (beg end)
  (interactive "r")
  (align-regexp beg end ",\\(\\s-*\\)" 1 1 t))
```

Then select the area and <kbd>M-x my-align-after-commas</kbd>

Comment: What's the `-` for in the regexp?

Comment: `\s-` means whitespace in Emacs regexp's (it's actually a syntax class, see the manual if you're really interested)

Comment: @mmmasterluke `\s-` is emacs' metacharacter for whitespace, as opposed to just `\s`. Emacs' regexes are a bit funky.

Comment: See `M-: (info "(elisp) Syntax Class Table") RET`, and also `"(elisp) Regexp Backslash"`. Each class is matched in a regexp with `\sCODE` for a given syntax class CODE (with `\SCODE` matching anything but).

Answer (score 5):

There's also the [columnize library](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColumnizeWords) which can transform this:

```
(defvar enform-keywords-statements
  '( "AT END"  "AT  START" "CLOSE" "DECLARE" "DELINK" "DICTIONARY"     
     "EXIT" "FIND" "FOOTING" "LINK" "LIST" "OPEN" "PARAM" "SET"            
     "SUBFOOTING" "SUBTITLE" "TITLE" )
  "List of ENFORM statement keywords. Used to create the `font-lock-keywords' table.")
```

into this:

```
(defvar enform-keywords-statements
  '( "AT END"      "AT  START"   "CLOSE"       "DECLARE"     "DELINK"      
     "DICTIONARY"  "EXIT"        "FIND"        "FOOTING"     "LINK"        
     "LIST"        "OPEN"        "PARAM"       "SET"         "SUBFOOTING"  
     "SUBTITLE"    "TITLE"        )
  "List of ENFORM statement keywords. Used to create the `font-lock-keywords' table.")
```

You select the region you want to align and then `M-x columnize-text`.

EmacsWiki page on this and others:
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryAlignment

Answer (score 4):

Emacs does let you select rectangular areas, and it does let you edit whole columns. To delete a rectangular area, set the mark at one corner, point at the other, and then `M-x kill-rectangle`. You can add a rectangle of whitespace by marking it the same way, and then `M-x open-rectangle`.

This is just the way that *I* know how to do this; there are doubtless other, possibly better ways.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I want to shift the column (in this case) one space to the right, not delete it.  When I set the mark (assuming you mean C-space) then move the point to the other corner, it seems to select entire lines between the mark and point?

Comment: Sorry, missed your edit while I was typing, let's see what happens, thanks! :)

Comment: Or with `cua-selection-mode` on: `C-RET` at top corner to begin rectangle editing, `<down>` to the bottom corner, `SPC` to insert a space at the start of every row, and `C-RET` again to disable the rectangle. For documentation, use `M-x find-library RET cua-base RET` and search for the comments on "CUA rectangle support".